# Invalid prisma.model.create invocation in. Unknown arg `school_id` in data.subjects.create.2.school_id for type CreateWithoutInout

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, graphql, prisma

Ive got these 2 models

```
model School {
  id         Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String?
  center_no  Int?
  type       String?
  subjects   SubjectPool[]
}
```

```
model SubjectPool {
  id   Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String?
  code String?

  school    School?         @relation(fields: [school_id], references: [id])
  school_id Int?
}
```

And I'm trying to seed the database using this query in the seed.ts file

```
 await prisma.school.create({
        data: {
            ...school,
            subjects: {
                create: [ math, english, geography]
            }
        },
        include: {
            subjects: true
        }

    })
```

But the problem is that i get this error:

```
Unknown arg `school_id` in data.subjects.create.1.school_id for type SubjectPoolUncheckedCreateWithoutSchoolInput. Did you mean `class_id`? Available args:     
type SubjectPoolUncheckedCreateWithoutSchoolInput {
  id?: Int
  name?: String | Null
  code?: String | Null
  class_id?: Int | Null
}
```

It seems it cannot find the school id field on the Subjects Pool model which i believe is there.

This is the sequence of commands i run before i run into this error:

```
dropdb dbname
```

```
createdb dbname
```

```
npx prisma db push / npx prisma migrate dev (if i have made a change to the model)
```

```
npx prisma db seed
```

Im working with a postgres db. The full error:

```
 await prisma.school.create({
       data: {
         id: 1,
         name: 'kansenshi secondary school',
         center_no: 2783783,
         type: 'gov',
         province: 'copperbelt',
         district: 'Ndola',
         subjects: {
           create: [
             null,
             {
               id: 3,
               name: 'English',
               code: '234',
               school_id: null,
               ~~~~~~~~~
               class_id: null
             },
             null
           ]
         }
       },
       include: {
         subjects: true
       }
     })

Unknown arg `school_id` in data.subjects.create.1.school_id for type SubjectPoolUncheckedCreateWithoutSchoolInput. Did you mean `class_id`? Available args:     
type SubjectPoolUncheckedCreateWithoutSchoolInput {
  id?: Int
  name?: String | Null
  code?: String | Null
  class_id?: Int | Null
  schedule?: ClassScheduleUncheckedCreateNestedManyWithoutSubjectInput
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shows that you are adding the field `school_id` in the seed file. `school_id` references the `id` field of the `SubjectPool` model so it would be created for you when you create the `subject` relation. Also looking at the error log, you have some fields `province`, `district` that are not specified in the school model you shared. To fix your error, you can use the seed data I created based on the model you shared.

```js
await prisma.school.create({
    data: {
      name: 'School 1',
      center_no: 123456,
      type: 'gov',
      subjects: {
        create: [
          {
            name: 'Math',
            code: 'MATH',
          },
          {
            name: 'Science',
            code: 'SCI',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
```

Check out the docs on [Nested Writes](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#nested-writes) in relational queries using Prisma.